# Function.prototype.toString() does not always return valid JS. Why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eval

Consider the following class declaration:

```
class A {}
A.prototype.test1 = function test1() { console.log("test1") }
```

Evaluating the stringified version of `test1` produces valid JS, as we can see here:

```
const a = new A
eval(`(${a.test1})`)() // outputs "test1"
```

However, if we build our class in a different but fundamentally equivalent way:

```
class B {
    test2() { console.log("test2") }
}
```

Evaluating the stringified version of `test2` fails:

```
const b = new B
eval(`(${b.test2})`)() // SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

(it was stringified to `test2() { console.log("test2") }` which is not valid JS except when embedded in a class declaration)

I can understand stringified native functions being not evaluable, for example `"".indexOf.toString()` will return a string containing `[native code]` and I accept that.

But isn't there a way to guarantee that `Function.prototype.toString()` called on user-defined functions (that is, function from which the source code is available) produces valid, evaluable JS?

Comment: "*except when embedded in a class declaration*" - yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But isn't there a way to guarantee that `Function.prototype.toString()` called on user-defined functions (that is, function from which the source code is available) produces valid, evaluable JS?

No. It depends on the type of the function. [The specification requires the following](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-function.prototype.tostring):

> `toString` Representation Requirements:
>
> - The string representation must have the syntax of a *FunctionDeclaration*, *FunctionExpression*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, *GeneratorExpression*, *AsyncFunctionDeclaration*, *AsyncFunctionExpression*, *ClassDeclaration*, *ClassExpression*, *ArrowFunction*, *AsyncArrowFunction*, or *MethodDefinition* depending upon the actual characteristics of the object.
> - The use and placement of white space, line terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent.
> - If the object was defined using ECMAScript code and the returned string representation is not in the form of a *MethodDefinition* or *GeneratorMethod* then the representation must be such that if the string is evaluated, using `eval` in a lexical context that is equivalent to the lexical context used to create the original object, it will result in a new functionally equivalent object. In that case the returned source code must not mention freely any variables that were not mentioned freely by the original function's source code, even if these “extra” names were originally in scope.
> - If the implementation cannot produce a source code string that meets these criteria then it must return a string for which `eval` will throw a `SyntaxError` exception.

Since you have a *MethodDefinition* you get the representation of a method. If you have a function that is neither a *MethodDefinition* nor a *GeneratorMethod*, then you can likely get a representation that can be `eval`uated (third point), but even then, the spec says that implementation should return a representation that throws a syntax error, so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: That's currently the case but based on this: http://tc39.github.io/Function-prototype-toString-revision/#sec-function.prototype.tostring, it is suposed to change in the (near ?) future